# Encountering difficulties while migrating the Marklogic database from a Windows environment to Red Hat Linux

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I am attempting to transfer data between a Windows-based MarkLogic system to Red Hat Linux-based MarkLogic system using the approaches mentioned below, but I have encountered the following issues.

1. **MarkLogic replication:** configuring database replication between the Windows and Linux cluster and getting a problem coupling both clusters.

> **Error:** The platform of the local cluster (winnt) doesn't match foreign cluster (linux)

2. **MLCP copy:** I have also try MLCP copy approch but also getting below mentioned issue

> **Command :** mlcp.bat copy -mode local -input_host localhost -input_port 8003 -input_username admin -input_password admin -output_host xx.xx.xx.xxx -output_port 8003 -output_username admin -output_password admin -thread_count 12 -copy_properties true -max_split_size 1000

> **ERROR **contentpump.DatabaseContentReader: RuntimeException reading /thesaurus/copy/123456.xml :java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not buffer value as string
> 23/07/01 22:09:24 INFO contentpump.DatabaseContentReader: host name: localhost

Comment: I would call it a serious design flaw if a database product can't replicate across different platforms.

Comment: I remember that backup/restore expects the same platform, so the replication error doesn't surprise me. The MLCP copy looks like it ought to work. 

Try running an export instead of copy. When I've had trouble with an mlcp copy, exporting and then importing has sometimes worked instead.

Comment: Using tooling, it can migrate to other OS/FS . It cannot replicate because the concept of replicate in this instance is an active transactional database that replicates the active artifacts including indexes (which are FS specific).  As with what David Cassel stated, export and import. I suggest export to an archive and in many cases, a consistent snapshot.  See: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/export#id_43184 then copy export and import. The error you state sounds like content related. Check the document.. The error gives the URI and value.. Also remember No MLCP on same machine as ML.

Comment: If the above recommendations don't help. make sure you're not running Content Pump via a VPN. If in cloud, provision an instance in the same cloud network, then use that to export/import.